# composer require failing to install new package Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, composer-php

**My OS : Ubuntu 20.0
My PHP Version : PHP 7.4.15**

I'm working on a project based on Yii2 frame work, I'm trying to add a new package called "kartik-date-time-picker" using the below command :

```
composer require kartik-v/yii2-widget-datetimepicker "dev-master"
```

But it fails and giving me the output like :

```
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Warning from https://repo.packagist.org: You are using an outdated version of Composer. Composer 2.0 is now available and you should upgrade. See https://getcomposer.org/2
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package sunhater/kcfinder (locked at dev-master) is satisfiable by sunhater/kcfinder[dev-master] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for filipajdacic/yii2-cpanel-email-creator * -> satisfiable by filipajdacic/yii2-cpanel-email-creator[dev-master].
    - Removal request for filipajdacic/yii2-cpanel-email-creator == 9999999-dev
  Problem 3
    - robregonm/yii2-pdf dev-master requires php ^5.6 || ~7.0.0 || ~7.1.0 || ~7.2.0 || ~7.3.0 -> your PHP version (7.4.15) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - robregonm/yii2-pdf dev-master requires php ^5.6 || ~7.0.0 || ~7.1.0 || ~7.2.0 || ~7.3.0 -> your PHP version (7.4.15) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - robregonm/yii2-pdf dev-master requires php ^5.6 || ~7.0.0 || ~7.1.0 || ~7.2.0 || ~7.3.0 -> your PHP version (7.4.15) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Installation request for robregonm/yii2-pdf dev-master -> satisfiable by robregonm/yii2-pdf[dev-master].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

How I can solve this problem ? I'm running on PHP 7.4.15 Version and Ubuntu 20.0 Operating system.

**my composer.json :**

```
{
    "name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced",
    "description": "Yii 2 Advanced Project Template",
    "keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "advanced", "project template"],
    "homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "support": {
        "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
        "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
        "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
        "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
        "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.14",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "~2.0.0 || ~2.1.0",
        "dmstr/yii2-adminlte-asset": "^2.6",
        "kartik-v/yii2-export": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker": "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-field-range": "*",
        "2amigos/yii2-multi-select-widget": "*",
        "yii2mod/yii2-rbac": "*",
        "robregonm/yii2-pdf": "dev-master",
        "2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget" : "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-editable": "dev-master",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2": "dev-master",
        "wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform": "*",
        "filipajdacic/yii2-cpanel-email-creator": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "~2.1.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "~2.1.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "~2.0.0",
        "codeception/codeception": "^4.0",
        "codeception/module-asserts": "^1.0",
        "codeception/module-yii2": "^1.0",
        "codeception/module-filesystem": "^1.0",
        "codeception/verify": "~0.5.0 || ~1.1.0",
        "symfony/browser-kit": ">=2.7 <=4.2.4"
    },
    "config": {
        "process-timeout": 1800,
        "fxp-asset": {
            "enabled": false
        }
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://asset-packagist.org"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Problem1: you have defined a stable [minimum-stability](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability), therefore you can't install `dev` packages. Problem 2 is probably related to that as well. Problem 3: that package isn't (officially) compatible with PHP 7.4. You'll have to find another one, downgrade to PHP 7.3 or fork/alter the package manually if you want to make it work on your setup.

Comment: Thank you for reply @Jeto., can you tell me how to fix the problem 1 and 2 and where I need to make changes.

Comment: Yes now its worked!, i downgrade version of PHP to 7.3 and the problem 3 is fixed. then changed minimum-stablity to dev that solved 1 and 2 problem.
I have one question, what is difference here minimum-stablity : dev and stable ?

Comment: Did you read the link from my first comment? Basically, it specifies what is acceptable for your project: only `stable` dependencies (aka those that are considered to be released), or also include those that are still in development / not yet fully released or tested.

Comment: Which of the error messages are unclear to you? What have you tried to resolve them? Please add more details to your question by editing it